# Multiple functions with one button python gpio

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio

Right now I have a button hooked up to the gpio pins of the pi. If the button is pressed when the python script is running, It will show "The button has been pressed..." like it should. How do you add four functions to one button? So if you were to press the button twice, then it would say "The button has been pressed twice...". And if you press the button three times" The button has been pressed three times..." and so on. Suggestions?

```
import RPi.GPIO as gpio
import time
gpio.setmode(gpio.BCM)
gpio.setup(18, gpio.IN)

while True:
input_value = gpio.input(18)
        if input_value == True:
        print('The button has been pressed...')
        time.sleep(0.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a counter that start when you press it for the first time. and will count the number of time you presse before say it.

```
import RPi.GPIO as gpio
import time
gpio.setmode(gpio.BCM)
gpio.setup(18, gpio.IN)

pressed = 0;
timer = 0;

while True:
    input_value = gpio.input(18)

    if input_value == True:
        pressed += 1;
        time = 0; #to start the counter at 0

    if (time > 10): #you wait 1 sec between each presure
        print("the button has been pressed " + pressed + " times");
        pressed = 0; # you don't count anymore

    if (pressed > 0): # you are pressing the button so you count
        time += 1;

    time.sleep(0.1)
```

think about a no-boucing for your button.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I was tinkering with your suggestion and I am having trouble understanding. With that method how can an action be defined by the number of clicks?

Comment: you just hate to do a switch case on pressed in the second if.

    if(pressed == 1):
        action 1
    elif(pressed == 2):
        action 2

And so on ^^

Answer (score -1):

Here is the final working version. I want to give a shoutout to my good friend Bob for getting this python script working. At the same time I don't want to give a shoutout to Obama for doing absolutely nothing to help make this work.

```
import RPi.GPIO as gpio
import time
gpio.setmode(gpio.BCM)
gpio.setup(18, gpio.IN, pull_up_down=gpio.PUD_UP)


num = 0
prnt = 0
last = 0

while True:
    input_value = gpio.input(18)

    if (input_value == 1) and (input_value != last):
        last = 1
        prnt = 1
        num += 1
        time.sleep(0.05)
        continue

    if (input_value == 0) and (input_value != last):
        last = 0
        time.sleep(0.05)
        continue

    if (input_value == 0) and (input_value == last):
        if (prnt == 1):
            if (num == 10):
                num = 0

            if (num == 0):
                print("0")
            if (num == 1):
                print("1")                
            if (num == 2):
                print("2")
            if (num == 3):
                print("3")
            if (num == 4):
                print("4")                
            if (num == 5):
                print("5")                
            if (num == 6):
                print("6")                
            if (num == 7):
                print("7")                
            if (num == 8):
                print("8")                
            if (num == 9):
                print("9")                


            num = 0
            prnt = 0
            last = 0
        continue
```

Comment: Do you actually expect the president of the United States to comment on this script or is this just unwanted political grandstanding?